# Where to find composer's global packages?

Tags: php, sublimetext2, composer-php, sublimetext

For a plugin for Sublime Text I was required to install a composer package globally.

In order to do this I had to run the following command:

```
composer global require "asm89/twig-lint" "@stable"
```

The installation started running and a few seconds later the package was installed. Voila! Well, not really.

Step two was to add some lines to my Sublime Text configuration file:

```
{
    "user": {
        "paths": {
            "windows": ["C:\\Users\\yourname\\.composer\\vendor\\bin"]
        },
    }
}
```

However, the plugin is not working. So I decided to check the path. And it appears there is no `.composer` directory in my profile directory. It isn't in my `php` directory either. And I can't find it anywhere.

I would like to know if there's a way to locate this directory and would appreciate any suggestions that can help me get this plugin to work.

Answer (score 201, accepted):

You can query Composer to find where it has set the user `$COMPOSER_HOME` directory.

```
composer config --list --global
```

The `[home] ...` line refers to the default value of `$COMPOSER_HOME`.

---

The word `home` can be used as a single parameter as well to show the configuration value.

Example (Windows):

```
> composer -n config --global home                
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Composer
```

Example (Linux):

```
$ composer -n config --global home                
/home/<user>/.composer
```

---

Just as a final confirmation - the 'yourname' part in the configuration, would very likely need to be updated with your own Windows username - `composer config` will say where it puts the files.

Comment: About the `yourname` part. I figured :)

Comment: You can just run `composer config home`.

Comment: I believe in this instance it would actually be `composer global config home`

Comment: @EdwardSammutAlessi 
The global command allows you to run other commands like install, remove, require or update as if you were running them from the COMPOSER_HOME directory.

Documentation: [Composer. global command](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#global)

Comment: I get `/data/.composer` but there is no `/data/` folder in my Ubuntu install...

Comment: This worked for Windows 11

Answer (score 34):

You can use

```
composer global config bin-dir --absolute
```

Example

```
PATH=$(composer global config bin-dir --absolute --quiet):$PATH
```

You need `--absolute` to get value expanded, and `--quiet` to discard diagnostics of composer global changing working directory. This was tested with composer 1.10.16 and 2.0.1.

See https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/9354#issuecomment-716827067

Answer (score 9):

You may find in ~/.config/composer/vendor/bin

Comment: This is the case with my settings in Ubuntu 18

Answer (score 6):

Ubuntu 20.04:

`~/.config/composer/vendor`

Comment: This depends on composer version and environment configuration. You can also have it on Ubuntu 18.04 as you show it on Ubuntu 16.04 and vice-versa, even with the latest composer version IIRC.

Answer (score 3):

Run the command

```
composer config --list --global | grep -w home
```

You can find the find the `[home]` with composer path, similar to this one.

```
[home] /home/example_username/.config/composer
```

Comment: Better even not filter with grep but just return from the command directly. I edited the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30664521/367456) to show it, it was also in the comments there.

Answer (score 3):

For composer v2:

```
composer global config --list
```

Check the output and find `[vendor-dir]` parameter. Or use grep:

```
composer global config --list | grep "vendor-dir"
```

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, mine was `/Users/taylor/AppData/Roaming/Composer/bin`

Answer (score 0):

~/.config/composer/vendor/bin/laravel adding this to my bashrc file as a alias works on ubuntu 20.04