# Checking github.com oauth access: FAIL

Tags: php, docker, github, composer-php

**ENV:** docker , MAC-OS, i am running the below command.

```
composer diagnose
```

Getting following message

```
Checking composer.json: WARNING
No license specified, it is recommended to do so. For closed-source software you may use "proprietary" as license.

require.AB/Modules : exact version constraints (3.17) should be avoided if the package follows semantic versioning
require.

ABC/mongodb-library : exact version constraints (1.15) should be avoided if the package follows semantic versioning
require.tecnickcom/tcpdf : exact version constraints (6.2) should be avoided if the package follows semantic versioning
require.

ABC/dns-cache-client : exact version constraints (1.0.3) should be avoided if the package follows semantic versioning

Checking platform settings: The OpenSSL library (0.9.8zc) used by PHP does not support TLSv1.2 or TLSv1.1.


If possible you should upgrade OpenSSL to version 1.0.1 or above.

Checking git settings: OK

Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK

Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK

Checking github.com oauth access: **FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://api.github.com/" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed**

Checking disk free space: OK

Checking pubkeys: 


Tags Public Key Fingerprint: xxx

Dev Public Key Fingerprint: xxx


OK

Checking composer version: OK

Composer version: 1.8.0

PHP version: 5.6.21

PHP binary path: /usr/local/php5/bin/php

**Installed openssl**

    openssl version

LibreSSL 2.2.7
```

I have added token both globally with this command and composer.json also.

```
composer config -g github-oauth.github.com XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

https://www.previousnext.com.au/blog/managing-composer-github-access-personal-access-tokens
Still problem persist. anyone can suggest me how can i resolve the issue ?

Comment: Try and check your [global composer.json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30664521/1766219) to see if your there may have been a misspelling or something in there (as happend [here](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1558). There's something about that authentication that isn't right. ... You could also try and do it without the global parameter ( so just `composer config github-oauth.github.com XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` =>  Without the `-g` ) - and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

It worked by giving all the permissions:

-inside the htdocs folder of xampp, it doesn't work it's php version problem
-generate the folders on the outside and then copy and paste them on htdocs