# PhpUnit 9 fails with php 8+

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-plugin-creation

I tried using PHPUnit 9 but it is not supporting the latest version of PHP above 8.0
I am receiving this following error

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function each() in C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Util\Getopt.php:80 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(242): PHPUnit_Util_Getopt::getopt(Array, 'd:c:hv', Array) #1 C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(138): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->handleArguments(Array) #2 C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(129): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run(Array, true) #3 C:\xampp\php\phpunit(46): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() #4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Util\Getopt.php on line 80`

Comment: `each()` is now deprecated.

Comment: I don't think you're actually using the latest version of PHPUnit 9. Getopt.php no longer exists in the repository. https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/4629 has some suggestions

Comment: is there any solution for it? or any other platform where we can test WordPress Plugins

Comment: @aynber I have rechecked it, I am using PHPUnit 9.5.21. And I used the following command `➜ composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit ^9` to install in my root directory **C:\xampp\htdocs\test** and when I try to run the command `phpuni` in my plugin directory **C:\xampp\htdocs\test\wp-content\plugins\mypluginname** then it gives me this error. I am not sure where I am making mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you don't have a *Global* package installed with a lower version of PHPUnit.

[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30664521/3088045) to find the globally installed packages.

```
cd $(composer -n config --global home) && ls -la vendor
```

Maybe you are calling the global rather than the project one.
In case you can remove it with

```
composer global remove phpunit
```

I suppose your environment `PATH` variable includes the global Composer folder, so by default `phpunit` calls that one.
Otherwise, use `./vendor/bin/phpunit` (from the directory `C:\xampp\htdocs\test`) to call the specific version that you installed inside the project.